# Change table field based on where clause

Tags: mysql

I need to change some fields based on a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM  IP_cases_prelim
WHERE DRG = '470' AND PRINCIPLE_PROC_CD = '8154' 
      AND `Treatment Category Code` = '00601';
```

It finds 254 records in a table of 6000.

I now need to change the 'Treatment Category Code' just for these from '00601' to '00801'

Suggestions?

thanks

Comment: it seems like a joke....explain properly

Answer (score 0):

Try an *[update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)* statement:

```
UPDATE IP_cases_prelim 
SET 'Treatment Category Code' = '00801'
WHERE DRG = '470' AND PRINCIPLE_PROC_CD = '8154' AND Treatment Category Code = '00601';
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
UPDATE IP_cases_prelim
SET    'Treatment Category Code' = '00801'
WHERE  DRG = '470' AND PRINCIPLE_PROC_CD = '8154' 
       AND 'Treatment Category Code' = '00601';
```